# Where is the applicationDidFinishLaunching function?

Tags: xcode

My documentation says:

> Add the codes below into the applicationDidFinishLaunching function...
>   -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{

But I only see

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

Q: Are these two the same?

If not, where do I find the applicaitonDidFinishLaunching function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the Apple documentation:

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching:
```

Tells the delegate when the application has finished launching.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

This method is used in earlier versions of iOS to initialize the application and prepare it to run. In iOS 3.0 and later, you should use the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` instead.

Comment: I did a Google search for the phrase that you pasted and found this pdf file:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol.pdf.  Q: Is THAT the Apple documentation that you're referring to, or is there somewhere else that I should be reading before posting these questions?

Comment: Yes, that is the documentation, but also accessible on Apple's regular documentation page, here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

These are the same. The options have been added in the 4.0 SDK if I recall correctly.

Edit: it's been there since 3.0: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: the withOptions: method was added in 3.0, and the basic applicationDidFinishLaunching: is deprecated I believe.

Comment: I just checked the doc, it's not deprecated, just not included in the default template.

Comment: Well, not really deprecated. Reading the doc makes me think this one is called on pre-3.0 iOS, and the `...withOptions` is called on 3.0+