# Issue with adding buttons to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

So this is how I make the navbar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navBar willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    navBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    [self.view addSubview:navBar.view];
    [self addChildViewController:navBar];
    [navBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    ...
```

And everywhere I have read says that this is how you add buttons:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"test" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(print_message:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
[button release];
```

But the button does not show on the navbar. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your navigationbar probably differently:

In your xxxAppDelegate.m edit this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

//This is the ViewController of the view you want to be the root
xxxViewController *tvc = [[xxxViewController alloc]init];

//Now you have to initialize a UINavigationController and set its RootViewController
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tvc];

//Now set the RootViewController to the NavigationViewController
[[self window]setRootViewController:nvc];


self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

So now you have a proper NavigationController. If you do this in the viewDidLoad method, the NavigationController will be made each time you reload your view.

Now in your xxxViewController.m edit your init method:

```
- (id)init
{
...
if (self) {
 //Create a UINavigationItem
 UINavigationItem *n = [self navigationItem];

 //Create a new bar button item 
 UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"test"    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(print_message:)];
 [[self navigationItem]setRightBarButtonItem:button];
}
return self;
}
```

This should now display a proper NavigationBar with a UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: ok I have a question about the `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching `method. Theres one with a `void` return and theres one with a `boolean` return that has `WithOptions` at the end. In the void one I have `[window addSubview:myViewController.view];` and `[window makeKeyAndVisible];`. Will this code interfere with that code?

Comment: According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151378/where-is-the-applicationdidfinishlaunching-function the void one is an older version of applicationDidFinishLaunching. So if you want to keep compatibility for systems prior to iOS 3 you probably have to edit it in the void one.

Comment: ah ok. So is there a difference between setting up the ViewController and Window in the .h file with `IBOutlet...` and `@property...` versus doing the above?

Comment: The AppDelegate manages stuff for certain events like the start of an application or when you close it. Since you need the NavigationController immediately after the application launchs it makes sense to creat it when your application gets the message that the application launched properly. You do stuff in the .h file which  affects the view in a direct way like the UIBarButtonItem. So you could simplify it and say that global stuff of creating a View are in the AppDelegate and specific stuff is in the ViewController.

Comment: Ok so I removed my viewcontroller stuff from the appdelegate.h file and did it as you said. The navbar does show up now but the viewcontroller is empty. It doesn't show anything I had there before. Do i have to setup my scrollviews and imageviews differently now?

Comment: @gta0004: I really think you need to work through some introductory material about iOS app development, the application lifecycle, and view controllers. Maybe start with the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html)?

Comment: Sorry, I think I expressed myself badly. The ViewController has two parts, the h. and the m. file. In the h.file you declare your methods and instance variables, so that you can use them properly in the m. file where the actual code of the methods belongs. So in the m. file of your viewController you should set up your scroll- and imageviews. In the h. file you should declare methods, instance variables and set up connections (like IBOutlet). You do your whole stuff which specific your view in the viewController where the h.file is something like a menu card and the m. file the actual food.

Comment: Yeah I have that all setup. I just had `@property IBOutlet...` for my ViewController in the AppDelegate.h file as well which I changed to what you said. But now nothing shows up that used to show on the screen. I haven't changed my ViewController.h or .m except adding the init method. So I was just wondering if the calling convention for adding scrollviews and other stuff has changed.

Comment: Assuming you mean for example the IBOutlet for your UIScrollView (which should be in your ViewController.xib file), you have to adjust the connection between the IBOutlet (little dot straight left to it) to the UIScrollView in your .xib file. Did you do that?

Comment: Yeah, I did that all way before trying to set up the navbar and it was working fine and I haven't changed anything besides adding the navbar.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're building a custom container view controller (which is a relatively rare thing to do), you should not be building a UINavigationController inside your content controller's `-viewDidLoad`. While it will provide you a navigation bar, your view controller parent-child relationship will be backwards: your content controller will contain the navigation controller, rather than the other way around.

Instead, you need to create the navigation controller earlier in your app's startup process - maybe in your application delegate, or in your main storyboard if you're using one. Make sure that the new navigation controller has your content controller as its root controller (usually by way of `-initWithRootViewController:`). Then your `self.navigationItem` configuration will work properly.

Comment: where would I add it in the AppDelegate though? Is it gonna be in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching?